# Arranging 4 divs with same class name in css

Tags: html, css

I have 4 divs that I need to arrange properly but they have the same class name. I want to have a result like this > https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4oDV.jpg that is not changing when window is resized. I tried flexbox and I can't get the result I wanted. Thanks for the help

Edit: sorry I'm new to stackoverflow, here's the code below

```
<head>
<style>
    .box {
        background-color: yellow;
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 20px;
        background-clip: content-box;
        width: 500px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="box">
<h2 class="box-heading">heading</h2>
<p>box1 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></p>
</div>

<div class="box">
<h2 class="box-heading">heading</h2>
<p>box2 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></p>                     
</div>

<div class="box">
<h2 class="box-heading">heading</h2>
<p>box3 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></p>
</div>

<div class="box">
<h2 class="box-heading">heading</h2>
<p>box4 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></p>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't just post links to images, post your code, what you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: Please post code? Are you using any frameworks etc? What have your tried so far?

Comment: sorry, the code is now included, can you take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
  .child {
     margin: 15px auto 0 auto;
     width: 31%;
     height: 160px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border: 1px solid #000;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    <div class="myclass"></div>
    <div class="myclass"></div>
    <div class="myclass"></div>
    <div class="myclass"></div>


Now in your css

 .myclass{
      width: 31.33%;
     padding: 1%;
  }
  .myclass:nth-child(4) {
       margin: 0 auto.
  }
```

Comment: Center tag is not valid in css3.